# Avoiding multiple if exists, else if exits statement for different joins used inside

Tags: sql, join, if-statement, exists

Inserting in one common table with the different scenarios

E.g:

```
if exists(select id from tablename where  id =1 )
insert into Temp 
select * from tbl inner join ........
else if exists(select id from tablename where id=2)
insert into Temp 
select * from tb2 inner join ........
else if exists(select id from tablename where id=3 )
insert into Temp 
select * from tb3 inner join ........

....
```

it is like using else condition for joining different tables for different id's...
now i want to write a single query without this else if,else if... but based on the id value the respective select statement should be called

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking to define a query (or view) using SELECT, WHERE, and UNION ALL.  Consult the documentation (postgreSQL, MySQL, or whatever SQL dialect) for details.